# How to run the functions periodically while main is waiting for the server close

Tags: python, async-await

I have experience in C programming and new to Python. I would like to run fucntion1 and fucntion2 continuously instead of waiting for server to be closed. Right now the below code run the functions once and wait for the server. How to run the functions? Please help

```
async def main():
    function1()
    function2()
    server = await websockets.serve(
        on_connect,
        '192.168.1.251',
        9000,
        subprotocols=['ocpp1.6'],
        ping_interval = 10,
        ping_timeout = 120
        )
    logging.info("Server Started listening to new connections...")
    await server.wait_closed()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will verify and update here

Comment: I added the code and started the thread but it ran only once. I am printing some text which i can see only once in the output.

Comment: In `asyncio` you can run multiple tasks. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently

Comment: I want to run these functions repeatedly. I tried changing with await and async , still i can see the output only once and the socket server is running till it is closed .

Answer (score 1):

You can run the function 1 and 2 in two separate threads.

```
from threading import Thread
t1 = Thread(target = function1)
t2 = Thread(target = function2)
t1.setDaemon(True)
t2.setDaemon(True)
t1.start()
<your code to connect to server>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using schedule module

import aioschedule as schedule
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(func,parameters)

asyncio.run(schedule.run_pending)

Hope this can help someone. Thank you for all for your valuable suggestions.